# Is XHTML really Xtensible?

Tags: html, xhtml

Is there any way (server- or client-side) that I can actually extend HTML to include new tags?  For example, it would be cool if I could write something like a schema fragment that defined a `blogpost`, which contains a `postname`, a `postauthor`, a `posttime`, and a `postcontent`, and thereafter refer to `blogpost` in my HTML rather than resorting to the basic HTML `div` and `p` tags.

Comment: Another interesting question would be: If you just used those custom elements and applied CSS rules to them, in which browsers would that work (like out of the box)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) is right up your alley!

You can use elements like `section` to wrap up all your posts, and `article` for each post, plus basics like `header`, `nav`, and `footer`.  There isn't fine grained elements like postauthor or posttime but you can provide other attributes to help define these.

Hmm, seems I spoke to soon, you can use this too:

```
<time pubdate datetime="2010-11-13T20:00+09:00">Posted Nov 13.</time>
```

Comment: For a post time, the time element should have a `pubdate` attribute on it too.

Comment: Interesting, but this doesn't say XHTML is extensible, as asked: it merely says HTML5 is bigger, with even more tags and attrs included by default.

Comment: The direct question wasn't answered with a yes/no, however the OP wanted to be able to better manage his blogging content.  Since HTML5 is now the new "standard" and better manages this kind of content I suggested it and the OP felt it was a worthy option.

Answer (score 2):

That ***would*** be awesome.  [Here is an article](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=157) explaining why it won't work.  Basically, you can extend the markup.  But HTML browsers won't know how to interpret your new tags.

Comment: This is close to what I am talking about.  (Although I would probably attempt creating a new XML Schema before attempting to create a new DTD)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please. What does HTML browsers mean? All modern browsers except IE have a XML parser. Which browsers know how to interpret custom tags, and which don't know?

Comment: The referred article is incredibly dated ('Netscape Navigator'?).  Also I suspect that the browser isn't basing its interpretation of the file's content as HTML based on the file extension, as they claim.

Answer (score 0):

For the general web developer, no.  You'd need to write your own DTD to have your own tags, and even then, it really will not benefit you semantically for anything other than your own sanity.

Also, some browsers *ahem IE* will not know how to handle your custom tags, and you'll have to resort to JavaScript to teach it.  Not really recommended...

Comment: Can IE really not handle custom tags in an XHTML document with an appropriate DTD?

Comment: @Chuck, you are partially correct. According to the IE docs, you can use your own custom tags, but they must be namespaced or else it treats it as an unknown tag (meaning IE does not allow it to contain children).  Also, the namespace has to be declared in the HTML tag.  However, I've never tried to create my own DTD to test IE's support for un-namespaced elements given they are defined in the DTD.

Answer (score 0):

While the browser won't readily understand extensions based on the XML-derived extensibility, that doesn't mean people aren't working on this problem.

HTML5 additions like `<section>` aside, the best solution for what you're trying to do is probably [microformats](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Microformat). In the case of your blog example, [hAtom](http://ablognotlimited.com/index.php/articles/getting-semantic-with-microformats-part-5-hatom/).

Then you get something that browsers understand, but can be progressively enhanced as more systems support hAtom and you can style entries using class references like `.hentry`, `.entry-title`, and `.author`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* add custom tags to the DOM tree. You won't get valid XHTML, but browsers will understand those tags as long as you style them correctly.

A very interesting project making use of this browser behavior is **[WebODF](http://www.webodf.org/)**, a tool for bringing ODF documents to the browser. Check out the video on the site and the live demo to get some understanding how this works.

Comment: I guess I was recursing the acronym one step further.  XML stands for eXtensible Markup Language.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom tags by mixing XHTML with your custom language. The language is no longer XHTML but a compound language including XHTML, but that was always the intent of XHTML anyway.

You will, however need to use XHTML properly, and serve it with an XML mime type, such as application/xhtml+xml, which means no IE support before IE9.

You can see an example using blogpost, postname, postauthor etc here:

http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/custom1.xhtml.ashx

(Works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE9)

---

[Of course, you can just put invalid tags into HTML and style them, but to me, that doesn't seem to me to be the point of question, which was specifically about the extensibility nature of XHTML.]